# make chrome default browser

Tags: chrome-for-android, default-applications

I'm using Galaxy Note 2

Nowadays, every link in FB app and in Whatsapp is opened in the native browser

I want to make Chrome the defualt browser for all actions including these two apps.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Head to Settings -> Apps -> All -> Internet -> Clear Defaults. Next time you do a search or open a link, you'll be given a choice of which app you want to open it with. Select Chrome and put a tick in the "Make Default" checkbox and that should make Chrome the default browser.

Answer (score 1):

While [j0chn's description](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/41432/16575) works (and also does work for other "default apps"), it might not be the most user-friendly approach. As Android itself does not offer anything else, you might want to pick a helper. [Default App Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager) is such a helper:

[image: Default App Manager] [image: Default App Manager]
<sup>Default App Manager (Source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager)); Click images to enlarge</sup>

As the screenshots show, this app lists up default apps defined and lets you clear those defaults -- but it also lets you define them.

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

Go to *Settings→application manager→all*. There to "internet browser", click on that and delete that "is default". When next time started the desktop link asked me for default browser.